# Get first characters to a variable

Tags: variables, awk, sed, grep, centos

I have an output like this

I need to get the id 65a8fa6 as an variable to a new command.

I'm familiar with grep and use it to get the line I need. But how do I only pick the first 7 caracters.

This is where I'm now

```
vagrant global-status | grep  DB1
```

Output

```
65a8fa6  default vmware_desktop running     /Users/USER/Documents/Vagrant/centos7SN/DB1
```

Comment: `vagrant global-status | awk '/DB1/{print $1}'`. If `DB1` is expected only at the end after `/` use `/\/DB1$/` regex

Comment: Are you sure that only one line will math with `DB1`?

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** You could simply do this with `awk`. Simply look for string `DB` in line and then if its found then print 1st field of that line. Save the output into variable `var` and later you could use it for your use.

```
val=$(vagrant global-status | awk '/DB1/{print $1}')
```

OR for matching either `db1` OR `DB1` try in any `awk`:

```
val=$(vagrant global-status | awk '/[dD][bB]1/{print $1}')
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** If you have GNU `awk` and you want to use ignorecase then try:

```
val=$(vagrant global-status | awk -v IGNORECASE="1" '/DB1/{print $1}')
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** To get first 7 characters try:

> But how do I only pick the first 7 characters.

```
val=$(vagrant global-status | awk '/[dD][bB]1/{print substr($0,1,7)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed alternative:

```
val=$(vagrant global-status | sed -rn 's/(^[[:alnum:]]{7})(.*$)/\1/p')
```

Split the output of vagrant ... into two sections using sed and regular expressions (-r) Substitute the line for the first section only and print.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `cut` command to find instances of what you're after, provided that there's some consistent text near what you want to find:

Say you want to find `Hello` out of the following line:

```
Hello  here's some text blablablabla
```

You can find it doing something like:

```
echo Hello  here's some text blablablabla | grep text | cut -d "  " -f 1
```

Should output `Hello`

Comment: You might show how to get the id 65a8fa6 as an variable (7 characters) :
`id=$(vagrant global-status | grep  DB1 | cut -c1-7)`.